# Universal driver package location

Tags: driver, windows-10-universal

I'm upgrading a Win7/8 KMDF driver to Universal, and Microsoft seems to have deprecated package projects in favor of the built-in packaging option, if you have only a single driver in the solution, which is my case.

However, I can't seem to find a way to tell DriverPackageTarget the folder I want my output to appear in, it always seems to use build_folder\name_of_project. How can I change this without creating a package project?